# Get element by id using DomDocument on html page that is broken

Tags: php, html-parsing, domdocument

I am trying to extract only one div element having `id=MainText` from [this page](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stiff). However, when I load the contents of this page into the DOM object I get several errors:

```
Tag g:plusone invalid... 
Unexpected end tag...
htmlParseEntityRef: no name ...
htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' ...
```

So, I was thinking if it is possible to ignore all other stuff from the document and go straight to the part I want, get only the div element with that particular id.

Or else, is there an alternative to using domdocument class for achieving the samething? I'm not very good at writing regular expressions.

Comment: *"when I load the contents of this page"* - How do you do that, exactly?

Comment: @Tomalak: I hadn't decided how to do that yet. For testing purposes only I downloaded the page and put it in my local folder and then used the loadHTMLFile method

Answer (score 2):

The w3c validator, on a quick run,  spits a lot of errors. Try to get the html clean in this way before to feed it to DomDocument:

```
#Assuming that $html is your html source (retrieve it as you prefer)
$tidy = new tidy;
$tidy->parseString($html, $config, 'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML((string)$tidy);
```

Comment: Where can I find this "tidy" class? I tested the code here and php acused that this class doesn't exists.

Comment: @fabio: http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.installation.php (Google, first hit. Seriously.)

Answer (score 0):

Never use RegEx with HTML.

Stick with DOMDocument and maybe suppress the error if they don't cause further problems.

Comment: I had supressed the errors putting a '@' before the calling to the "loadHTML" method. What happens here is that some content gets lost like the very "div id=MainTxt" element itself - which is the exact thing I need to extract.